# Phonegap Android: Prevent Sleep by Programatic User Activity

Tags: android, cordova, sleep

I have a Phonegap Android app that scans RFID chips. Apparently scanning RFID does not count as a user action, because the device will go to sleep after the interval set in Android Settings (which is a maximum of 10 minutes).

So despite constant scanning, my device will go to sleep. So I need a way to tell the OS that I'm active, programtically after each RFID scan.

Currently, I am doing something that I don't want, which is using

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

to prevent sleep while the app is running, but I'd like to still be able to use the sleep interval if the device is actually inactive.

I had high hopes for using `powerManager.userActivity(l, false)` but apparently this is only available for System apps, so I cannot set permission for it.

Any ideas how to keep the device active while not doing any touch screen interaction?

Comment: Have you tried using `PowerManager.newWakeLock()?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A WakeLock is the answer, but the key is to use `ON_AFTER_RELEASE`. With this flag, the user activity timer will be reset when the WakeLock is released.

So for the NFC plugin, under the onPause method I added:

```
MyMainActivity ma = (MyMainActivity) cordova.getActivity();
wl = ((PowerManager) ma.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE))
    .newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "wakeywakey");
wl.acquire();
```

And under the onResume method I added:

```
wl.release();
```

With this arrangement, when an RFID chip is scanned, the NFC plugin will create the WakeLock and then release it, which will reset the activity timer. Also, I used `SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK` even though it is deprecated, as this will brighten the screen if it has gone dim.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this cordova plugin

> https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin

To prevent sleeping you call:

```
window.plugins.insomnia.keepAwake();
```

and to allow sleeping again:

```
window.plugins.insomnia.allowSleepAgain();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to play with JAVA a bit.

Add this code to your activity class:

```
 PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
 PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
 wl.acquire();
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) you will find more info.

Also dont forget to relese WakeLock at the end:

```
 wl.release();
```

You also need to be sure you have the WAKE_LOCK permission set in your Manifest.